# AutoMapper: to update an existing collection

Tags: c#, automapper

it's fairly simple to map an existing entity using this

```
Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source, destination);
```

but I want to update an existing collection, like:

```
        var class1List = new List<Class1>
        {
            new Class1 { Id = 1, Name = "Name1", Text = "Text1"},
            new Class1 { Id = 2, Name = "Name2", Text = "Text2"},
            new Class1 { Id = 3, Name = "Name3", Text = "Text3" },
        };

        var class2List = new List<Class2>
        {
            new Class2 { Id = 1, Name = "a" },
            new Class2 { Id = 2, Name = "b" },
        };

        ObjectMapper.Map<List<Class1>, List<Class2>>(class1List, class2List)
            .Key("Id"); //here I'd supposedly specify a key to map the objects but there is no such a method
        /*
           the desired result is an updated collection with one new item:
            class2List = new List<Class2>
            {
                new Class2 { Id = 1, Name = "Name1", Text = "Text1"},  //this is updated by Id
                new Class2 { Id = 2, Name = "Name2", Text = "Text2"},  //this is updated by Id
                new Class2 { Id = 3, Name = "Name3", Text = "Text3" }, //this is a new object because there were no matching Id in the list
            }
        */
```

Is it possible to do this through AutoMapper?
Because without specifying a Key to map, it actually just returns a collection of 3 new Class2 items that have nothing to do with the initial collection.

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, it was exactly what I needed. If you write it as a full-fledged answer I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

[The fine manual](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) for automapper collections implies you configure the ID equivalency elsewhere e.g. something like

```
mapperconfig.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>().EqualityComparison((c1, c2) => c1.Id == c2.Id);
```

and then you can map a collection of Class1 to a collection of Class2